# How to get a machine-readable list of fixtures in Pytest?

Tags: pytest, fixtures

Pytest's `--fixtures` option allows to list all fixtures defined in a project. However, it outputs the results to the shell in which the command was called, in a **human-readable** format.

What would be the easiest way to get the list of fixtures programmatically, in a **machine-readable** format, either by the `pytest`'s CLI or API ?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on where you're running the command and where you want to put the result. On Linux, for example, you can just run `pytest --fixtures > fixtures.txt` and you'll have the output on the text file.

**Update**

After your comment, I think your best option is to use the `--setup-only` flag because it will show the fixtures used on each test. You will have to process the result somehow, though. On Linux, again for the example, you could do something like `pytest --setup-only | grep "fixtures used:" > fixtures.txt`, which would give you a file with only the lines showing the fixtures used on each test, but you would have to iterate over each line to extract the fixtures names and create a list without repeating them to get what you want.

**Update 2**

After your comment on the other answer, I think you can achieve what you want by using the [`pytest_collection_modifyitems(session)` hook function](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html?highlight=pytest_report_to_serializable#pytest.hookspec.pytest_collection_modifyitems), which will give you access to the `session` object which is the object used to print whatever is returned by running `pytest --fixtures`. You can see how that is built [on this line on pytest's source code](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/f43ddd8acd74a2c3242a3874420072836e0614aa/src/_pytest/python.py#L1597). Therefore, with the `session` object, you can access the `_fixturemanager` attribute and then the `_arg2fixturedefs` with `session._fixturemanager._arg2fixturedefs` which will return the fixtures with all their details which you can the use to create the file however you want.

**Update 3**

Using what I mentioned above, I made a plugin to achieve what you want: https://pypi.org/project/pytest-json-fixtures/

It still needs a lot of stuff, but it's working fine. Please let me know what you think.

Comment: Sorry, the question was probably not phrased well, I'm not trying to find how to redirect the output of the command but how to get a machine-readable list of fixtures.

Answer (score 0):

- using cli `pytest --fixtures > fixtures.txt`
- converting it to code

```
 def test_get_fixtures():
        os.system("pytest --fixtures")
```

Comment: Sorry, the question was probably not phrased well, I'm not trying to find how to redirect the output of the command but how to get a machine-readable list of fixtures.

Comment: could you elaborate what sort of output you are expecting

Comment: Anything would work tbh: JSON, XML or native Python objects containing fixture names, module and docstring for instance